# Angular 5 : Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword

Tags: typescript, angular5

I am trying to get the Date.now(); When the enter key is pressed but I get an error instead. : (

There doesn't seem to be a whole lot on the net regarding this error either.

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
onEnter(event){
   if(event.key === "Enter"){

 this.calculateTime();
    }
  }

calculateTime(){
    if(this.date === undefined){
        this.date = new Date.now();
    }
  }

}
```

Error is:

> error TS2350: Only a void function can be called with the 'new'
>   keyword.

Any idea why I get this error and how may I go about fixing it?

Cheerio.

Comment: What do you think this `new Date.now();` should do ?

Comment: ah I see, Date.now() is a static method. Hence I don't need to call new. This is basically what the other answers said when I looked into it. I just wasn't sure how this related to my case. It all seems clear now. Can you leave an answer so my question doesn't have to go unanswered. Cheers buddy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Date.now()` function is a static method, so you don't need to instantiate it with the `new` keyword. I think you are getting mixed up when trying to get a current date object by calling `new Date()` and this function mixed up.

Hopefully this helps!